# Proving that for a group $(G,\star)$ the opposite operation $a\star'b:=b\star a$ defines a group isomorphic to $G$.

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism, binary-operations

The question I am working with is

> Let $(G,\star)$ be a group. Define the map $\star ':G \times G \rightarrow G$ by $a\star 'b =b\star a$ for $a,b \in G$.

I was able to prove that $(G, \star ') $ is in fact a group, but after looking around the web,and reading through my text, I am having overall troubles finding how to prove $(G, \star ') $ is isomorphic to $(G,\star)$.

I know the definitions and that I need to show $\varphi(ab) = \varphi(a)\varphi(b)$ and that $\varphi$ is bijective, but am stuck on how to actually do it.

Comment: It’s confusing as can be, but the $\varphi$ that you want is probably $\varphi(a)=a^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks that was suprisingly helpful

Comment: Is the bijection simply trivial because both groups consist of G?

Comment: Yes, the bijectivity follows directly from the fact that the sets are the same.

Answer (score 3):

The group you define is known as the *opposite group* of $G$, and is often denoted by $G^{\operatorname{opp}}$. Every group $G$ is canonically isomorphic to its opposite group by the map
$$G\ \longrightarrow\ G^{\operatorname{opp}}:\ g\ \longmapsto\ g^{-1}.$$