# Prove group and opposite group are isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, group-isomorphism

Let $\langle G, ∗\rangle$ be a group, and suppose $∗'$ is a binary operation on $G$ defined by $a∗'b=b∗a$ for all $a,b \in G$. I also proved in the previous problem that $\langle G, ∗'\rangle$ was a group. What I'm thinking is:

Proof: Let $\langle G, ∗\rangle$ be a group, and suppose $∗'$ is a binary operation on $G$ defined by $a∗'b=b∗a$ for all $a,b \in G$. From the previous example we know that $\langle G, ∗'\rangle$ was a group. We know that $\langle G, ∗'\rangle$ contains all elements of that $\langle G, ∗\rangle$ since the only difference is the operation. Therefore, the groups have the same order, and thus are 1-to-1. Given that $*'$ is defined as $a∗'b=b∗a$ for all $a,b \in G$, this is essentially the commutative property to $*$. So, $a∗'b=b∗a$ and $b∗'a=a∗b$ thus making it an onto mapping. Therefore, they are bijective. Hence, $\langle G, ∗\rangle$ and $\langle G, ∗'\rangle$ are isomorphic as groups.

Is my reasoning sound?

Comment: Just for reference, such a structure is known as the [Opposite Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_group)

Comment: Your argument isn't enough.  You need to show that the natural map is in fact a group homomorphism.  (this is largely just a matter of writing down what that would mean).

Comment: @lulu the previous example was to show that the new binary operation created a group with $G$. So I showed associativity, that there was an identity, and inverses in the previous example. Do I need to do it again instead of just citing that we know from the previous example that it is a group?

Comment: Yes, I misread what you wrote and thought you still need to show it was a group.  So, given that that part is done, you still need to prove that the natural map is a group homomorphism.  It is obviously a set theoretic bijection but you need to prove that it respects the group law.

Comment: Correction:  the identity map does not work unless the group is abelian, so you need to find one that does.  The link I sent initially provides an example, but you might want to try to come up with one on your own.

Comment: One thing with [tag:solution-verification] questions is that users need to specify what it is about their proof/solution they're unsure of. Asking us to assess an entire proof is too broad.

Comment: From the tag wiki: "A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough"

Comment: This question has also been [asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1448683/104041).

Comment: See [this meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20583/104041) about solution verification posts that are *sans* context.

Comment: @Shaun ok, I won't ask any more questions.

Comment: Please do ask more questions, @Tacosi! Don't be discouraged; you're new. We don't bite.

Comment: @Shaun, I'm sorry, but sometimes it seems like you do.

Comment: There's only so much one can convey in 600 characters. Long, informal conversations are discouraged. People might seem terse, dismissive, impatient, *etc.*, but it's really a product of the forum style. We're friendly once you get to interact with us enough! $$\ddot\smile$$

Answer (score 3):

> Proof: Let $\langle G, ∗\rangle$ be a group, and suppose $∗'$ is a binary operation on $G$ defined by $a∗'b=b∗a$ for all $a,b \in G$. From the previous example we know that $\langle G, ∗'\rangle$ was a group. We know that $\langle G, ∗'\rangle$ contains all elements of that $\langle G, ∗\rangle$ since the only difference is the operation. Therefore, the groups have the same order, and thus are 1-to-1.

When you say 1-to-1, you need first give a map, $\phi:G\to G'$, and show $\phi$ is 1-to-1. How is your $\phi$ defined here?

> Given that $*'$ is defined as $a∗'b=b∗a$ for all $a,b \in G$, this is essentially the commutative property to $*$. So, $a∗'b=b∗a$ and $b∗'a=a∗b$ thus making it an onto mapping. Therefore, they are bijective. Hence, $\langle G, ∗\rangle$ and $\langle G, ∗'\rangle$ are isomorphic as groups.

The general step to prove $G$ and $G'$ are isomorphic is:

1. give a map $\phi: G\to G'$
2. show $\phi$ is one to one
3. show $\phi$ is onto
4. show $\phi$ is a homomorphism, namely, $\phi(a*b)=\phi(a)*'\phi(b), ~~\forall a,b\in G$

Answer (score 2):

The map $x \mapsto x^{-1}$ is an isomorphism from $(G,*)$ to $(G,*')$.

Answer (score 2):

The identity mapping, although bijective, doesn't respect the group structure. So, you need to come up with a different bijection which is also a homomorphism of groups.

Hint : The new operation, although drastically different from the old one, does have the same identity element and the same inverse for each element.

How about the map $x \mapsto x^{-1}$ ?

---

As a side note, if you are aware of a bit of category theory (ignore, if not), then the new group is just the dual/opposite of $G$, considered as a single object groupoid. So what this says, is that a single object groupoid is isomorphic (as a category) to it's dual.

Comment: Do I express this as: let $\phi: \langle G,*\rangle \to \langle G,*'\rangle$ be defined as $\phi (x)=x^-1$? Then go through the $\phi (a*b)=\phi(a)*'\phi(b)$?

Comment: Yes. Precisely. You also need to check that $\phi$ is bijective.

Comment: doesn't 1-to-1 follow from G being in both groups? Or do I have to explicitly state that since $\phi(x)=x^-1$ and since each element has only one inverse that it is 1-to-1? For onto, I'm a little less clear what to do.

Comment: No, one-one doesn't follow from $G$ being in both groups. You can have mappings of a set into itself which are not one-one. In this case, the precise mapping $\phi : x \mapsto x^{-1}$ is one-one since as you said, each element has only one inverse. For ontoness of $\phi$, just observe that if $y \in G$, then $\phi(y^{-1}) = y$.